# Replacing all occurrences of one class name with another with jQuery

Tags: jquery, addclass, removeclass

Say I have a UL with the ID of "menu". If I wanted to find all the list items of that menu that have a class of "foo", remove the "foo" class and add the class "bar", how would I do this with jQuery? Here's what I've got so far. My syntax is a bit off.

```
$('#menu').children().hasClass('foo').removeClass('foo').addClass('bar');
```

Also, if the list item didn't already have the "foo" class, then I don't want it to have the "bar" class, either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just select all the items you want with the selector query:

```
$("#menu > .foo").removeClass("foo").addClass("bar");
```

`#menu > .foo` selects all direct children of `#menu` that have class `.foo`.

Answer (score 0):

`.hasClass()` returns a boolean value

```
$('#menu > .foo').removeClass('foo').addClass('bar');
```

or try

```
$('#menu > .foo').toggleClass('foo bar');
```